# Java out of bounds error but I am sure it's declared properly

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

This GUI is made from javax.swing. I'm wondering why it throws Array Index Out of Bounds exception but I'm sure that it's declared properly. I also tried running tests inside the for loops of the instantiation of the cells and the resetting of the cells but it still won't work. When I tried printing the i and j of the loop in the resetFields actionEvent it doesn't really go out of bounds but it says it goes out of bounds.

I found out that col adds one to itself when it goes to the actionPerformed function which is kinda weird.

NOTE: I get the row and col from the main class in another Java file.

Here's the full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ExperimentalFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private int row, col;
    private JTextField cells[][];
    private JPanel matrix;
    private JButton compute1;
    private JButton reset;
    private JButton showSolution1;
    private JButton resetFields;
    private JPanel matrixPanel;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JLabel theory;
    private JPanel theoryPanel;
    private JLabel header[];

    public ExperimentalFrame(int row, int col)
    {
        this.row = row; this.col = col;
        theoryPanel = new JPanel();
        theory = new JLabel("Theory here");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        matrix = new JPanel();
        matrixPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        cells = new JTextField[row][col];
        header = new JLabel[col];
        compute1 = new JButton("Compute");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");
        showSolution1 = new JButton("Show Solution");
        resetFields = new JButton("Reset Fields");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        matrixPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        matrix.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        theoryPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        compute1.addActionListener(this);
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        showSolution1.addActionListener(this);
        resetFields.addActionListener(this);

        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        gbc1.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        theoryPanel.add(theory);
        mainPanel.add(theoryPanel, gbc1);

        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridx = j + 2;
            if (j != (col - 1))
                header[j] = new JLabel("I" + (j + 1));
            else
                header[j] = new JLabel("x");
            matrix.add(header[j], gbc);
        }

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                gbc.gridx = j + 2;
                gbc.gridy = i + 3;
                cells[i][j] = new JTextField(3);
                System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                matrix.add(cells[i][j], gbc);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = i + 3;
            matrix.add(new JLabel("Equation " + (i + 1) + ": "), gbc);
        }

        gbc2.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        gbc1.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        matrixPanel.add(matrix, gbc1);
        gbc1.gridy = 2;
        gbc1.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10);
        matrixPanel.add(compute1, gbc1);
        matrixPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 2;
        mainPanel.add(matrixPanel, gbc1);
        //gbc1.gridy = 3;

        gbc1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc1.gridx = 1; gbc1.gridy = 1;
        gbc1.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0);
        buttonPanel.add(reset, gbc1);
        gbc1.gridx = 2; gbc1.gridy = 1;
        buttonPanel.add(resetFields, gbc1);

        gbc1.gridx = 1; gbc1.gridy = 3;
        gbc1.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, gbc1);
        add(mainPanel);

        pack();
        setTitle("Experimental");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        Object o = ae.getSource();
        JButton jb = (JButton) o;
        if (jb == reset)
        {
            this.setVisible(false);
            this.dispose();
            new Experiment10();
        }
        else if (jb == resetFields)
        {
            System.out.println(row + " " + col);
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                    cells[i][j].setText(""); //here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:6
    at ExperimentalFrame.actionPerformed(ExperimentalFrame.java:140)
```

Comment: Can you add the exception trace as well as the line in the code segment shown where the exception occurs please?

Comment: I added it. It's at line 140.

Comment: We don't know what line is line 140.  If I copy this into an editor, line 140 just has a `}` on it.  I think we can tell which one it is, but next time please include a comment in your source to tell us which line is being referred to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the class variables (row, col) and iterate based on the array size. There is no need to maintain row and column variables once the array is created.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + j);
            cells[i][j].setText("");
        }
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Your idea is way better but I still  don't get why it adds one to itself. Lol.

Answer (score 4):

It's because, when you declare `cells = new JTextField[row][col];` `col` is not equal to `this.col` (`this.col = col + 1`)

So when you go for `for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)` in `actionPerformed` `j` is out of bound for `this.cells`

For example, when you instantiate your class with col = 5, the cells will be created with a 5 width, however, this.col will be equal to 6, and j will go the 5 value in you for loop.

To correct you issue, do that

```
public ExperimentalFrame(int row, int col){
        this.row = row; this.col = col;
```

or, if you really need col to be increased by one, which I personnaly think is odd,

```
public ExperimentalFrame(int row, int col){
        col++;
        this.row = row; this.col = col;
```

Comment: Still ain't it. The col adds one to itself when it gets to the actionPerformed function which is weird.

Comment: I agree with Xavier, that you do not have exact no of array elements.

Comment: I already tried using this.col in the for loop. It still ain't working.

Comment: Okay. I removed it. But still, it adds one to itself. I removed the +1.

Comment: Jessie, are you sure you still reproduce the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ?

Comment: @Jessie It looks like you edited out the `+1` in your original question, which makes it very confusing to read answers.  Please don't do that.